# Validate email with JOI Library

Tags: node.js, validation, joi

I already use JOI to validate many different things. Now I need to validate an email as well.

Validation logic looks like this:

```
const emailSchema = Joi.string().email({ minDomainSegments: 2 }).lowercase().required();

const resource = Joi.validate(email, emailSchema);
if (resource.error !== null) {

  return true;
}
```

The thing is it fails to validate the following format:

> const email = 6AEFE056-485C-42C0-9059-AF4D614C8FBE@anon

It sees it as a regular email, but it is not.
It does work with regular emails.

What am I doing wrong? I would really want to use JOI for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joi version that I have used is [14.3.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi)

And coincidentally that is the last version on NPM. Joi moved under [Hapi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi)
And while being with Hapi, they release several new versions. The way I was using a version was designed for a newer release, but not mine. Therefore, I used older version notation.

When I find time, I will also switch to newer version.

This is the sample that works with older version.

```
const emailSchema = Joi.string().email({ minDomainAtoms: 2 });
```

Comment: this also fails on 14.3.1 , unfortunately this also pass an email as d@s.c